# How to get target type from pallet_vesting?

Tags: pallet

after importing pallet_vesting, one of the pre-built pallets https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/pallet_vesting/pallet/enum.Call.html

I have imported `sp_runtime`

```
use frame_support::{
    pallet_prelude::*,
    sp_runtime::traits::{Hash, StaticLookup, Zero},
    traits::{Currency, LockableCurrency, ReservableCurrency},
};
use pallet_vesting;
```

I would like to use the following functions from that pallet_vesting source code:

```
  fn add_vesting_schedule(
    who: &T::AccountId,
    locked: BalanceOf<T>,
    per_block: BalanceOf<T>,
    starting_block: T::BlockNumber,
  ) -> DispatchResult {...}

pub fn vested_transfer(
  origin: OriginFor<T>,
  target: <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source,
  schedule: VestingInfo<BalanceOf<T>, T::BlockNumber>,
) -> DispatchResult {...}
```

I have figured out those types:

`OriginFor<T>` for origin type

`BlockNumberFor<T>`, for starting_block `T::BlockNumber` type

`T::AccountId`, for my target or destination arguments

`BalanceOf<T>` for locked type and per_block type

```
  type BalanceOf<T> =
    <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
```

But that `T::AccountId` is not compatible with the vested_transfer() function's target type! See the error message below:

type annotations needed
cannot satisfy `_: pallet_vesting::Config`rustcE0283
lib.rs(281, 10): required by a bound in `pallet_vesting::Pallet::<T>::vested_transfer`

how can I import the correct target type?

further digging into the source code, I got this:

```
use sp_runtime::traits::{StaticLookup, Zero};
...
  impl<T: Config> Lookup for ChainContext<T> {
    type Source = <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source;
    type Target = <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Target;
    ...
  }
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add the code that exhibits the error you are encountering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just assuming that you are looking for some syntax to mention the associated types of a type that implements `StaticLookup`. Should work like this:

```rust
type SourceOf<T> = <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source;
type TargetOf<T> = <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Target;
```

Comment: Hi Alexander! Thanks, after adding your TargetOf<T>, now I got this error: associated type `Lookup` not found for `T`,   how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on where you try to use this type alias from. You probably need to ad some trait bound on `T`.